# KOHANA 3.2.0 don't select column

Tags: php, kohana, inner-join, kohana-orm

i have two joined tables. Now i need to print out some columns, but problem is that i have Firms.Id and FirmsUnique.Id columns. When i try to ->select("*") kohana 3.2.0 throws error: *"Column 'Id' in order clause is ambiguous"*

```
$firms = ORM::factory('firm')
    ->select("Firms.Id", "FirmsUnique.*")
    ->join("firmsunique")
    ->on("Firms.FirmUID", '=', 'FirmsUnique.Id')
    ->order_by('Id', 'ASC')
    ->where('ProjectId', '=', $projectid)
    ->group_by("FirmsUnique.FirmName")
    ->limit($pages->items_per_page)
    ->offset($pages->offset)->find_all();
```

How do i deselect column? Or i have to type manualy all columns that i want? (->select("Firms.Id", "Firms.ProjectId" ... etc))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->order_by('Id', 'ASC')
->where('ProjectId', '=', $projectid)
```

to

```
->order_by('Firms.Id', 'ASC')
->where('Firms.ProjectId', '=', $projectid)
```

Also you can use `echo $firms->compile(Database::instance());` before  calling `find_all()` method to inspect your query and try to execute it in MySQL directly to find some bugs and errors.

Comment: echo Database::instance()->last_query; exit();   does the same thing to show the last query executed. Put that right after you execute the query though.